# Disable Record Navigation SHIFT+TAB in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have form that loads as Data Entry = Yes and the navigation buttons are disabled.  I'm trying to figure out how to make it to where a user cannot press SHIFT+TAB and go back through previously entered records.  You have to press tab at the very last field to move to a new record just like you would the table.

Should I just close and reopen the form after update?  Or is there a different way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but are sure you have Data Entry=Yes in your form? By definition, if True, that property should remove the existing records leaving just a new record row. I also tested it and it worked as advertised on a test form.

Comment: It is set to yes because when I open the form it begins a new record, but if I enter a record and hit tab to bring up a second new record, I can view the data from that record I just entered.  I cannot view any other records though, just the ones I've entered that session while the form remains open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I answer the question, are you sure preventing the user from going backwards is a good idea?  Perhaps they tabbed forward to make a new record and then realized they made a mistake so they want to go back and correct it?  Of course, this depends on the specific needs of your db and how it will be used.

The **Cycle** property in the **Other** tab defines how tabbing works.  If you change this to **Current Record**, then the user cannot tab backwards or forwards to other records.

If the user needs to add multiple records at once, you can add a command button.

#### Edit

Regarding your idea on the submit button, here's how you can make that work.  Leave the form's record source blank (so it isn't tied to the table).  When the users click Submit, a msgbox will first pop up asking them to save and warning them they can't go back.  If they choose Yes, a SQL query stored in the VBA will then append the form's values to the target table, then clear the form.

The only potential problem with this is if the user enters single or double quotes to any string fields as those can mess up your SQL query.  A simple Replace() can fix that though.

Comment: I do see your point.  That is a discussion I will need to have the user whom I'm helping build this for.  But I did not know about the Cycle property.  Good info.  I suppose I will either allow the user to navigate through the session or add a submit button to create a new record.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. If you want to go with the submit button, see the edit to my post for a way you can make that work.